# Windows azure Worker Role weekly email sending

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles, azure-worker-roles

How to send weekly email report using Worker Role in windows azure application

Answer (score 1):

Correct, if you use Mobile Services, you can set certain scripts to run on a fixed time interval very easily. A once/week interval is certainly supported.  Details can be found at: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/schedule-backend-tasks/

If you are already running an app on Cloud Services, however, you may want to look at using the Scheduler add-on in the Windows Azure Store.  SendGrid is probably the easiest option for email because you can also add it to your subscription through the Store.
Documentation for sending email using SendGrid with Windows Azure is available here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/sendgrid-email-service/
Details on the Scheduler add-on are available here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/store/service/?name=scheduler
Details on SendGrid, including the free offer for Windows Azure customers, are available here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/store/service/?name=sendgrid

Answer (score 0):

[SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/) is an easy-to-use service for sending e-mails if you have no other way from within the role.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a worker role, may I recommend you use Windows Azure Mobile Service. The reason I recommend using this is because it natively supports task scheduling. You can read more about it here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/schedule-backend-tasks/. Also look at an example of sending emails using Send Grid with Windows Azure Mobile Service here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/send-email-with-sendgrid/. You just combine these two to have an application which would send emails on a weekly basis.